# What is difference between media.session.MediaController and android.widget.MediaController?

Tags: android

I am using "android.widget.MediaController" for VideoView. Not sure when to use "android.media.session.MediaController" and what the difference is between them. Any idea?

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: One is graphically displayable, the other is not.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation explains the difference very well. One is a view that offers controls for a media player; the other is an object fo interacting with an ongoing media session.

Description of [android.widget.MediaController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html):

> A view containing controls for a MediaPlayer. Typically contains the buttons like "Play/Pause", "Rewind", "Fast Forward" and a progress slider. It takes care of synchronizing the controls with the state of the MediaPlayer.

Description of [android.media.session.MediaController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.html):

> Allows an app to interact with an ongoing media session. Media buttons and other commands can be sent to the session. A callback may be registered to receive updates from the session, such as metadata and play state changes.